# Why i cann't connect to a secured WebSocket server?

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, ngrok

can't connect to a secure WebSocket running through a Python 3.10 script.
The client itself is on Node.js.
And so, the error that appears in the developer console when trying to establish a connection
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://5.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16233/' failed:`

The connection to WebSocket itself is through Ngrok, which is run in my case through:
`ngrok tcp 3000 tcp://5.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16233 -> localhost:3000.`

Next comes my python script which runs WebSocket itself on the local machine via:

```
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain("cert.pem", "cert.pem")

async def start_server():
  print("server started")
  await websockets.serve(new_client_connected, 'localhost', 3000, max_size=9000000,ssl = ssl_context)
```

(The ssl_context is more important here).

I start the client through the

> https://localhost:8080/
> (There is an error in the console saying that the certificate is not valid.)
> sockjs.js?9be2:1603 GET https://192.168.0.105:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1667580226809 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

The certificate is self-signed and is created using OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem
```

My guess is why it doesn't work for me:

1. Something is wrong with the certificate.
2. I am trying to run ngrok with the wrong command

P.S. The python script doesn't show no error, although i think it doesn't catch no new connections.

I have tried to restart the ngrok server, as well as changing the protocol.

Comment: My understanding of what you are doing: 1. You use ngrok to do a TCP forwarding - so no TLS setup or changed by ngrok itself.  2. You use a self-signed certificate in your websocket server.  - But a self-signed certificate is not trusted by the browser, so you get the error saying net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. All of this has nothing to do with ngrok, it will happen also if you run websocket server and browser on same machine or in same network without ngrok. If you want to use a self-signed certificate, then you need to make the browser trust it explicitly first.

Comment: Could please give me an understanting of how can i make the browser trust it.

Comment: Actually it is ok, when i connect my client to the localhost with wws WebSocket, it works ok, the ngrok itself doesn't receive the requests

Comment: I see an access in the console to `https://192.168.0.105:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1667580226809` - which is not the URL for ngrok. So you access the wrong URL in your application. This is kind of confusing - you have the ngrok URL on 5.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16233 which does not seem to be used, you access some server at localhost:8080 which you don't explain anywhere and from this you access 192.168.0.105:8080 which is not explained anywhere too. So it is unclear to me what you are actually doing.

Comment: OK, so look. I have the client and the server, the server is written in python and is lauched on the port 3000, and the client is a vue app that is being launched on the port 8080.

Comment: But where is your app accessing the websocket? The error message you show is not about the URL of the websocket.  Nowhere in your question you show how you access the websocket from your application and what happens if you try to do this.